# Is there a way to read data from csv and write data to csv in c# without using a data table?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, csv

In a tool development, I need to access data from a csv file and create another csv and write the data in different place(different columns) there. IS there a way I can do it without using data table?

Comment: Your question is too broad, there are multiple ways of reading the csv and storing the data without using a `DataTable`, a quick google search will tell you that much

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use a data table.

You can also just read it with a filereader and split. Sameway you can write it with for example a stringbuilder.

Example of the read:

```cs
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\document.csv"))
    {
        List<object> list = new List<object>();
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(';');

            list.Add(new {a = values[0], b = values[1]});
        }
    }
```